# Prove that $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \sqrt{9-x} + 3 = 6$

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Prove that $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \sqrt{9-x} + 3 = 6$

So far my difficulty is trying to find a $\delta$ that will allow for this function to be less than $\epsilon$.  I keep getting that $|\sqrt{9-x}+3-6|=|\sqrt{9-x}-3| < \epsilon$, but from here I do not know how to deal with finding  $\delta$.  Thanks in advance and any help is appreciated.

Comment: If you have results about continuous functions you're allowed to use, then by far the easiest is to note that $f(x)=\sqrt{9-x}+3$ is continuous in a neighborhood of $0$ (namely $(-\infty,9)$) and therefore $\lim_{x\to 0}f(x) = f(0)$.

Comment: Sorry I don't know that result, or anything about continuous functions.  All I know is the definition of a $\epsilon-\delta$ definition of a limit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$|\sqrt{9-x}-3|=\frac{|x|}{\sqrt{9-x}+3}\leq\frac{1}{3}|x|$, you can set $\delta=3\epsilon$.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Multiply by $\sqrt{9-x}-3$ by $\dfrac{a}{a}$ where $a=\sqrt{9-x}+3$.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, observe that for any $ x \in (- \infty,9] $, we have
\begin{equation}
|\sqrt{9 - x} - 3||\sqrt{9 - x} + 3| = |(9 - x) - 9| = |x|.
\end{equation}
Fix an $ \epsilon > 0 $. Then choosing any $ x $ that satisfies $ |x| < \min(9,3 \epsilon) $, we obtain
\begin{align}
|\sqrt{9 - x} - 3| &= \frac{|x|}{\sqrt{9 - x} + 3} \\
                   &= |x| \cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt{9 - x} + 3} \\
                   &< 3 \epsilon \cdot \frac{1}{3} \\
                   &= \epsilon.
\end{align}
Hence, we can set $ \delta := \min(9,3 \epsilon) $.